# How to ask for `hostname` in a script that is run remotely

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, cygwin

I want to have host A run script on hosts B,C,D by `ssh`. The script needs to know hostname of host (is it B, C or D?).

I came across the following problem when I executed the following script on host A:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh Adam@$1 <<'EOF'
echo 12345`hostname`ABC
EOF
```

I get `ABC45myhostB` instead of `12345myhostBABC` for hostname `myhostB`.

Host A is Ubuntu server 10.4 32bit, and hosts B,C,D are Windows XP running openssh from cygwin.

Comment: Looks like output of `hostname` includes a carriage return (`\r`)

Comment: Have you tried echo "12345`hostname`ABC"?

Comment: >Looks like output of hostname includes a carriage return

Yes, it does. But only if executed remotely. The same command works just fine, when executed locally on the same machine.

Comment: What happens if you manually run the echo command on `myhostB` itself, rather than through `ssh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to use the environment variable HOSTNAME instead

echo abc${HOSTNAME}def or something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
uname -a | grep -i cygwin && {
echo 12345${COMPUTERNAME}ABC
} || echo 12345`hostname`ABC
```